# Defining prototype property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a class, let's say `A`. I need to declare there a prototype property that can be accessible as follows:

```
var idKey = A.prototype.attributeId;
```

I can do it using the following code:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
      A.prototype.attributeId = "InternalId";
  }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: you definitely don't want to define it in the constructor, otherwise the prototype will be redefined everytime the constructor is called!

Comment: @AlexanderMills, you are right. I definitely didn't want to define it in the constructor. thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not ideal, but it suits your needs.

```
class A {
    attributeId: string | undefined;
}
A.prototype.attributeId = "InternalId";
```

This gets compiles to es5 as:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    return A;
})();
A.prototype.attributeId = "InternalId";
```

Comment: this is great but it causes another typescript error : Property 'attributeId' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.(2564)

Comment: @mtx you can use the `!` to bypass that error `attributeId !: string;`

Answer (score 8):

Here's another way, using decorators:

```
function setProto(value: any) {
    return((target: any, key: string) => {
        target[key] = value;
    });
}

class A {
    @setProto("InternalId")
    attributeId:string;
}
```

It gets compiled to some glue code (defined only once) and:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    __decorate([
        setProto("InternalId")
    ], A.prototype, "attributeId");
    return A;
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @jjrv answer, so I made Typingly correct version:

```
function setProto<T>(value: T) {
    return function <K extends string>(target: Record<K, T>, key: K) {
        target[key] = value;
    };
}

class A {
    @setProto("InternalId")
    attributeId:string;
}

class B {
    @setProto("6") // ERROR!
    length: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that uses class decorators and generics to ensure that you don't assign to a property that doesn't exist on the class:

```
const mixin = <B>(behaviour: B) => <M extends B, TFunction extends Function>(Class: TFunction & {new(...args: Array<any>): M}) => {
    Reflect.ownKeys(behaviour).forEach(key => {
        if(key !== 'constructor') {
            if(Class.prototype.hasOwnProperty(key))
                console.warn(`Warning: mixin property overrides ${Class.name}.${key}`);
            Object.defineProperty(Class.prototype, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(behaviour, key))
        }
    });
    return Class;
};

@mixin({
    bar: 'baz'
})
class Foo {
    bar: string;
}

const foo = new Foo;
console.log(Foo.prototype.bar, foo.bar, foo.hasOwnProperty('bar'));
// prints baz baz false
```

Inheritance works fine and modifies only the sub-class prototype:

```
@mixin({
    zip: 7,
    bar: 'zaz'
})
class Zoo extends Foo {
    zip: number;
}

const zoo = new Zoo;
console.log(zoo.zip, zoo.bar, foo.bar);
// prints 7 zaz baz
```

Answer (score -5):

Yes, if you are targeting ECMAScript5 or above then you can use the following property syntax on a class

```
   class A {
        private internalId: number = 1;
        get attributeId() {
            return this.internalId;
        }
        set attributeId(newVal) {
            this.internalId = newVal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not correct, since internalId's value exists for every instance of the class A and not once. Also the initialization code runs every time you create an instance of class A. @Martin's answer is the correct